I am using pycharm 3.12 and I am tring to Connect with IBM DS and I tryes every option using Chart gpt but Still I am geting this issue
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\rcheekurumilli\PycharmProjects\pandasDataframearrtmethod\pythonProject1\IBM TO PYCH.py", line 1, in <module>
import ibm_db
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ibm_db: The specified module could not be found.
I am trying so hard but I coudn't find any solution if any one know
